# Como crio um slide automático com JavaScript, HTML e CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide, webdesign

Sou iniciante e meu primeiro projeto é dividido por etapas, é um projeto até que um tanto bobo, mas me mantém animada em continuar estudando e tudo o mais. Basicamente, é como se fosse uma coleção de skins que quero comprar do Lol, bem simples e tudo.

Eu criei um slide que mostrava as skins que eu mais queria, ele funciona e tudo o mais. Eu pesquisei bastante mas não entendi como posso fazer para deixar ele automático, como um slide que passa a imagem depois de alguns segundos, mas que eu poderia ainda assim continuar clicando nos botões de navegação dele para ver alguma que eu quero.

Eu vi alguns vídeos usando somente o CSS, mas não soube como aplicar porque a estrutura parece ser muito diferente, então estou buscando algum meio de usar o JavaScript para isso. Sou bem iniciante, mas estou aprendendo, e se for muito complexo eu vou procurar aprender e entender o que tenho que fazer!

É isto, vou deixar o HTML e CSS aqui embaixo caso seja necessário.

```
       <!-- Slide -->
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="slides">
                <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide1" checked>
                <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide2">
                <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide3">
                <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide4">

                <!-- Imagens dos slides-->
            <div class="slide s1">

                <img src="https://earlygame.com/uploads/images/_body/Spirit-Blossom-Aphelios.jpg" alt="Aphelios Spirit Blossom">
            </div> 
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/127/1274050.jpg" alt="Sett Spirit Blossom">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FdHHhPpWAAI0yxR?format=jpg&name=4096x4096" alt="Evelynn Spirit Blossom">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FhiSXCNWIAIeL5D?format=jpg&name=medium" alt="Diana Natal">
            </div>


                <!-- Barra de navegação -->
            <div class="navigation">
                <label class="bar" for="slide1"></label>
                <label class="bar" for="slide2"></label>
                <label class="bar" for="slide3"></label>
                <label class="bar" for="slide4"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



CSS:


/* Estilo do Slide */

main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.content{
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    display: flex;
}

.bar{
    width: 70px;
    height: 17px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar:hover{
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.slides input{
    display: none;
}

.slides{
    display: flex;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: .6s;
}

.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: 0%;
}

#slide2:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -20%;
}

#slide3:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -40%;
}

#slide4:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomei a liberdade de rescrever todo o projeto. Espero que nao se importe e que meu codigo te ajude. <3

```js
let count =1;
document.getElementById("radio1").checked = true;

setInterval( function(){
    nextImage();
}, 2000)


function nextImage(){
    count++;
    if(count>4){
        count = 1;
    }

    document.getElementById("radio"+count).checked = true;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slides{
    width: 400%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
}
.slides input{
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
}
.slide img{
    width: 800px;
}
.manual-navigation{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.manual-btn{
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}
.manual-btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.manual-btn:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
#radio1:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#radio2:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -25%;
}
#radio3:checked ~ .first {
    margin-left: -50%;
}
.navigation-auto div{
    border: 2px solid #20a6ff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}
.navigation-auto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 360px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.navigation-auto div:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
#radio1:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn1 {
    background-color: white;
}
#radio2:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn2 {
    background-color: white;
}
#radio3:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn3 {
    background-color: white;
}
#radio4:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn4 {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <title>TESTE</title>
</head>
</header>   
<body>

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
            <!-- Botoes -->
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
            <!--Fim Botoes -->

            <!--Imagens -->
            <div class="slide first">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
            </div>
            <!-- Fim Imagens -->
            <!-- Navegacao auto -->
            <div class="navigation-auto">
                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="manual-navigation">
            <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
            <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```